# How can I filter search results?

Tags: 7, search

I need to restrict certain search results from showing up for users and limit them to a specific content-type. This can be either the main search or some sort of custom search since it's the only type of post that will need to be searched on the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options. The quickest solution is to use [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) and take advantage of its quick and easy, powerful filtering capabilities. Views is a must in using drupal. If I was you and you are expecting to be heavily reliant on search then look into using [search_api](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) and views together to create some nice mashups.